# SQL LIKE + wildcard operator only returns results with first value

Tags: database, subquery, wildcard, sql-like, db-browser-sqlite

What's happening StackOverflow.

I'm using *DB Browser for SQLLite* to query a database with two tables - `people` and `states`. `people` has the field `state_code` and `states` has the fields `state_abbrev` and `state_name`. `people.state_code` and `states.state_abbrev` both have postal codes for USA states (e.g. AK, AZ, MI, MN, etc.).

I'm trying to search for all records where the state names match a certain text string criteria, using LIKE and wildcards. Here's my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE state_code = (
    SELECT state_abbrev FROM states WHERE state_name LIKE 'mi%');
```

I want the above code to return all records where the state name begins with "mi" - i.e. Michigan, Minnesota, and Missouri. However, this is only returning records with the first alphabetical state name - *Michigan*. Same happens with `LIKE '%ans%'` - this only returns records from Ark*ans*as, despite the existence of records from K*ans*as.

What am I doing wrong yall? I've tried using `GROUP BY state_name, state_abbrev` within the nested `SELECT` to no avail, and I can't seem to find anyone else encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using  `WHERE state_code IN (...` this will search for all the records in your inner sql query